# Does goroutine go back into waiting mode if they cannot acquire lock after getting Signal() or Broadcast()

Tags: go, concurrency

Suppose I have the following function.

```
func acquireResourceAndDoSomething(resourceA, resourceB int) {
    lock.Lock()
    for !isBothResourceAvailable(resourceA, resourceB) {
        isBothResourceAvailable.Wait()
    }

    isResourceUsed[resourceA] = true
    isResourceUsed[resourceB] = true

    fmt.Printf("Doing something with resource #%v and #%v\n", resourceA, resourceB)

    lock.Unlock()
}
```

If I have 3 gorountine G1, G2 and G3.

- G1 requires resource A and B.
- G2 requires resource B and C.
- G3 requires resource B and D.

Suppose G3 is working and holding resource B and D, leaving G1 and G2 waiting in the loop. Eventually when G3 completes and calls `Broadcast()` after releasing B and D, I'm expecting both G1 and G2 to wake up at the same time and check the condition simultaneously. Obviously, only 1 of them would get the lock to move on.

My question is suppose G1 is the one who got the lock 1st to move on and acquire resource A and B. If G1 calls `Unlock()` without releasing A and B, would G2 wake up, get the lock and continue as if resource B and C are available or would G2 double check the condition to go into waiting mode again?

I'm new to Golang so I'd really appreciate your explanations :).

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking about a condition variable, during `Wait` the lock is unlocked, so other goroutines can work. If we're using sync/Cond, as the documentation states:

> Because c.L is not locked when Wait first resumes, the caller typically cannot assume that the condition is true when Wait returns. Instead, the caller should Wait in a loop:

So once `Wait` returns, there is no guarantee that the condition holds, only that the condition held at some point since it started waiting. But it is guaranteed that the goroutine has the lock, so it has to check for the condition again, and `Wait` if the condition no longer holds.

Comment: Are you saying that technically G1 and G2 will NEVER wake up at the same time even if both get `Broadcast()`? My understanding from what you wrote is only G1 or G2 will wake up then get the lock then check the condition again. My assumption was both G1 and G2 wake up at the same time, check the condition and only then try to acquire lock.

Comment: They BOTH wake up, and one will get the resource. You have to *manually* check the condition again.

Comment: Let me rephrase a bit. Suppose both G1 and G2 wake up at the same time, the 1st thing both of them do is to try to acquire the lock, *not checking the condition*. Only one (say G1) will manage to acquire the lock, and then it move on to check the condition, if it is valid, then it moves out of the loop, do its things, and release the lock (without necessarily releasing the resource). G2 then gets the lock, checks the condition, but it's not valid coz' G1 never release resource, so it goes back into waiting mode. If what I just describe is true, then the loop is enough to cover all scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

When `Go routine` wait to acquire lock, first time it acquired it when it release. But if there is a `Go routines pool`, Randomly one is get the lock.

But it doesn't know what internally happens. Inside the function it acquired the lock, whether it can wait or not. It decides with runtime condition.

Consider below simple code

You can use two locks and simulate the scenario like below. Inside the function, Go routines have to wait for another lock to acquire. It getting inside the function and wait for second lock. It doesnt know about lock2 and waiting time until get lock 1 and run after code.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var lock = new(sync.Mutex)
var lock2 = new(sync.Mutex)

func main() {
    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        i := i
        wg.Add(1)
        go test(wg, i)
    }

    wg.Wait()
}

func test(wg *sync.WaitGroup, i int) {
    defer wg.Done()
    fmt.Printf("waiting for lock 1 at G%d\n", i)
    t := time.Now().UnixNano()
    lock.Lock()
    fmt.Printf("acquired lock 1 at G%d after %d nano secs \n\n", i, time.Now().UnixNano()-t)
    lock.Unlock()

    fmt.Printf("waiting for lock 2 at G%d\n", i)
    t = time.Now().UnixNano()
    lock2.Lock()
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    fmt.Printf("acquired lock 2 at G%d after %d nano secs \n", i, time.Now().UnixNano()-t)
    lock2.Unlock()

    fmt.Printf("Done at G%d\n\n", i)
}
```

One of random output to prove the behaviour. Here all Go routines acquired first lock but wait for second lock to unlock by each Go routines. So, It doesn't know about second lock until go to the function

```
waiting for lock 1 at G2
acquired lock 1 at G2 after 0 nano secs 

waiting for lock 2 at G2
waiting for lock 1 at G1
acquired lock 1 at G1 after 0 nano secs 

waiting for lock 2 at G1
waiting for lock 1 at G0
acquired lock 1 at G0 after 0 nano secs 

waiting for lock 2 at G0
acquired lock 2 at G2 after 1000000000 nano secs 
Done at G2

acquired lock 2 at G1 after 2000000000 nano secs 
Done at G1

acquired lock 2 at G0 after 3000000000 nano secs 
Done at G0
```

run in [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/vpv74xs0Pih)